# read data from BigQuery table with java spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, google-bigquery

I have a Java application (using spring boot with jpa and hibernate) that reads data from a microsoft SQL DB currently, another team migrated all that data to bigquery. My problem is finding answers on whether I'm scrapping that integration and starting from scratch or if I can somehow leverage what is there. I have several DataSources in my project that all work in unison to populate a db2 database with all the sweet info. I've tried using the Simba and CData Drivers in place of what I had previously in my application.yml. 
what i have:

```
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://host:port;databaseName=awesomedb
    username: coolname
    password: notspecial
    initialize: false
```

what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
    driver-class-name: com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc42.Driver;
    jdbcurl: jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;
    ProjectId: {server};
    OAuthType: 0;
    OAuthServiceAcctEmail: {user};
    OAuthPvtKeyPath: C:\Users\meeee\Documents\svc-project.json
```

I know that url is all one line, or according to simba's setup guide. this is an enterprise application, so there's the normal firewall, fancy keep you out stuff, the json key was provided to me, and was tested for working status. I've set the env variables for the project and keypath (GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS), I've also tested using the format i pasted and the format of having it all as one string. I tested this connection in dbvisualizer and the intellij built in database tool. depending on the configuration I'm testing I'll either get a timeout/url error on the db test connection or in the java stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc42.Driver;
```

my current configuration in my pom includes:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-bigquery</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

in conjunction with their boms, this is my first time posting a question i hope i've included enough info.

adding stack trace(i've changed some things since then though i'm still getting errors, this is current):

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100004) HttpTransport IO error : {0}.
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.createAndTestClient(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.serviceAccountOAuth(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.core.BQConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.helpers.JdbcHelperImpl.connect(JdbcHelperImpl.java:590)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:303)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:279)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:209)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:161)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy232.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseConnectionEstablisher.connect(DatabaseConnectionEstablisher.java:227)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseConnectionEstablisher.tryConnect(DatabaseConnectionEstablisher.java:168)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseConnectionEstablisher.lambda$establishConnection$1(DatabaseConnectionEstablisher.java:104)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$null$6(AsyncUtil.java:129)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$static$0(AsyncUtil.java:39)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$thenComposeAsync$7(AsyncUtil.java:127)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$processWhenComplete$8(AsyncUtil.java:145)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$processWhenComplete$8(AsyncUtil.java:145)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenCompleteStage(CompletableFuture.java:883)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:2251)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:143)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.processWhenComplete(AsyncUtil.java:141)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$null$6(AsyncUtil.java:129)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:585)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:531)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.underProgress(AsyncUtil.java:166)
    at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$null$2(AsyncUtil.java:63)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:238)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.simba.googlebigquery.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100004) HttpTransport IO error : {0}.
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.createAndTestClient(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.serviceAccountOAuth(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.core.BQConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.helpers.JdbcHelperImpl.connect(JdbcHelperImpl.java:590)
    at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteDriverImpl.connect(RemoteDriverImpl.java:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.simba.googlebigquery.support.exceptions.GeneralException: EXEC_JOB_TIMEOUT_ERR
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.waitToRetryOrStop(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.insertJob(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.prepare(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Looks like the used class is not to be found in the declared dependencies (your POM file).

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I've added the full stack trace for my current issue, I changed some code around but the root problem still seems the same.

Comment: Are you able to resolve this? I am looking for something similar.

Comment: @PanwarS87, I never got back to solving this. though i experienced a similar situation with Azure when we moved some services over. After the same amount of long frustrating hours hitting a wall and going around in circles with other team i found out it was a netwroking issue and the IPs that the call was made from could change and would need a 'range' of ip addresses. I hope this helps sorry for the late reply